# Customizing JSON log emission format for Serilog

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, serilog

I'm using serilog in my asp.net app with configuration like that:

Configuration:

```
builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, loggerConfiguration) =>
{
    loggerConfiguration
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .WriteTo.Console(new RenderedCompactJsonFormatter(), standardErrorFromLevel: LogEventLevel.Information);
});
```

and usage:

```
var sensorInput = new { Latitude = 25, Longitude = 134 };
_logger.LogInformation("{@SensorInput}", sensorInput);
```

Result is like that. as you can see `sensorInput` information is in both @m field and `SensorInput` field. I would like it to be only in SensorInput, is it possible?

[image]

Also I would like to change names of special fields like @t to: timestamp, @m to message etc,. is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that [`RenderedCompactJsonFormatter` is pretty hardwired](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-formatting-compact/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Formatting.Compact/Formatting/Compact/RenderedCompactJsonFormatter.cs). The `Rendered` refers to the fact that includes the rendered form too, i.e. this is very much intentional (there are sibling formatters that don't include the rendered output, which address the 'less redundant stuff' part of your question, but not your full needs).

More generally, [`Serilog.Expressions`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-expressions) is the tool for the job if you want stuff that's more interesting. The README is pretty complete (and don't forget there's always neat tests illustrating things). There's also articles Nick has written such as:

- https://nblumhardt.com/2020/10/programmable-serilog-formatting/
- https://nblumhardt.com/2020/10/serilog-expressions-user-defined-functions/
- https://nblumhardt.com/2021/03/serilog-expressions-2/
- **https://nblumhardt.com/2021/06/customize-serilog-json-output/ (via @Nick below - specifically covers JSON emission)**

Comment: `Serilog.Expressions` is a bit difficult to get your head around but is definitely the right tool for the job.

Comment: Mentioning https://nblumhardt.com/2021/06/customize-serilog-json-output/ because it covers JSON formats specifically